# Will removing 'const' from a variable in my C++ cause me issues later on?

Tags: c++, constants

I am debugging some C++ code, and want to change the value of a variable inside a particular function. That variable was passed as a parameter to the function using the `const` keyword, for example:

```
void setRequest(const &data){
    ...
}
```

I now want to change the value of the variable `data` inside this function. As I understand, I won't be able to do this because `data` has been passed to the function as `const`.

What I am wondering, is what effects will removing the keyword `const` from the parameter have other than allowing me to change the value of `data` inside the function? Is there the possibility that this will break some other part of the code? What are the pitfalls that I should look out for when removing the `const` keyword?

Obviously doing this will affect any other functions that use the `data` variable, but given that the information it holds will always be the same type, I wouldn't have thought it would cause any major issues- is this correct?

An example of what I want to do would be:

```
void setRequest(&data){
    ...
    bool match = false;
    ...
    if(someCondition){
        match = true;
    }
    if(match == true){
        data = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the variable is not given by const reference instead ? It looks like a bad implementation. Moreover, your code is not C++. What is `data` ? A type ? Or the name of the variable ?

Comment: Aplogies- I missed the `&` from the start of the parameter...

Comment: There's no way of knowing if it will cause issues without seeing all the code that is affected by that function. It is for you to figure out.

Comment: @someone2088 be careful as answers that were very correct before you added the `&` (such as @SigTerm's answer) do not apply anymore to your updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will removing 'const' from a variable in my C++cause me issues later on?

It really depends on what you're planning to do with that variable.

> I now want to change the value of the variable data inside this function. As I understand, I won't be able to do this because data has been passed to the function as const.

If you only remove `const`, the "data" you receive within the function will be a copy of original variable. So, even if you change it, the original variable will remain untouched.

To modify the original variable, you need to use a reference (if the data is always provided), or a pointer (if the data is optional)

> is what effects will removing the keyword const from the parameter have other than allowing me to change the value of data inside the function?

Removing the const parameter will increase chance of making a bug which might waste hours of your time. Example" `(data = x)` instead of `(data == x)`. With const in place you'll catch this problem immediately, regardless of your compiler. That's the only side effect.

> Is there the possibility that this will break some other part of the code?

It depends on the contents of your function. For example, if you take a pointer to (reference to) non-const data within the function, store that pointer in a global variable and later access that data via that pointer later elsewhere, it will almost certainly break a lot of code.

> What are the pitfalls that I should look out for when removing the const keyword?

Const is a safeguard made for programmer. `const` reduces chance of making a mistake. By removing const, you increase your chance of making a mistake. If `non-const` parameter is passed **by value**, that mistake will pretty much amount to accidental modification of parameter, and those effects will be contained within the function. If `non-const` parameter is a **reference**, then it affects whether accidental modification will be visible outside of it.

There are also numerous ways to shoot yourself in both feet at once by passing (WARNING: bad programming practice) pointers to your parameter through external/global variables. That is pretty much guaranteed to make a big mess.

Generally you want to keep all your **reference** parameters const unless you **have** to change them.

With simple data types (such as int) keeping **value** parameters const is not strictly necessary, but is worth it if there's a high possibility of random modification.

You will also want to keep all class methods that do not change the class’s internal state `const` as well.

Small things like this keep you in control of the situation when your codebase grows very big.

Comment: Thanks for your answer- really helpful explanation. You're right- I originally missed the `&` from the variable- have added that in now.

Comment: @someone2088 unfortunately this answer no longer applies to your question since you modified it.

Comment: @TartanLlama it does say that to modify the original value, I need to use a reference or a pointer- now that I have amended the typo in my OP to include the pointer, is there something different you would say in reply to my OP?

Comment: @someone2088 removing `const` from a reference parameter has very different consequences. See my answer below, or the one from @JohnB

Answer (score 3):

Ok, you updated your code, so… Since `data` is passed by *reference*, your change will not only allow you to cause side effects to any code *outside* of your function (so… unpredictable side effects), but **you'll break the API** of your function by requiring the arguments of the function *not to be const*.

Comment: `const` is a security for typo and an information for the optimizer.

Comment: Hopefully, today's compilers are smart enough to figure out which *local* variables don't change by themselves — I'm not talking about pointers, there.

Answer (score 1):

It might have *any* effect, e.g.

```
struct A {
   void doSomething () { cout << "This called"; }
   void doSomething () const { cout << "That called"; }
};

void callWithConst (const A data) { data.doSomething (); /* prints "That called" */ }

void callWithoutConst (A data) { data.doSomething (); /* prints "This called" */ }
```

It depends on how the type of `data` is implemented and how it is used within the function.

Similarly with reference parameters.

If you remove `const` for testing purposes, you might test something different than you intended to test, since the code executed may be completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `const` from a reference parameter is very different from removing it from a value parameter.

The latter is mostly there to stop you doing something stupid, but what you propose is a fairly major interface change because assumptions about the mutability of the argument are no longer valid. You should consider all uses of setRequest and see if it will break any client code before making such a change.

If you can see that no code will be affected by it, then go ahead and make the change. This will include updating any documentation which is involved and maybe even the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine, as long as you are passing 'data' by value. const is there just to prevent you from changing 'data' inside your method.

Comment: It's also an information for the compiler the optimizer can take into account.